# Python regex to remove alphanumeric characters without removing words at the end of the string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to clean some text by removing alphanumeric characters from the end of the string, but I'm also removing normal words as shown on the **output**. Can someone help me achieve the expected result?

```
re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9/]{5,}$', '', text)

asus zenfone 3s max zc521tl
asus zenfone max plus (m1) zb570tl
asus zenfone max pro (m1) zb601kl/zb602k
nokia 3.1 c
nokia 3
asus zenfone 3 zoom ze553k
asus zenfone 3 deluxe zs570kl
blackberry keyone
htc explorer
lg tribute
acer liquid z520
```

**Output:**

```
asus zenfone 3s max 
asus zenfone max plus (m1) 
asus zenfone max pro (m1) 
nokia 3.1 c
nokia 3
asus zenfone 3 zoom 
asus zenfone 3 deluxe 
blackberry 
htc 
lg 
acer liquid z520
```

**Expected output:**

```
asus zenfone 3s max
asus zenfone max plus (m1) 
asus zenfone max pro (m1)
nokia 3.1 c
nokia 3
asus zenfone 3 zoom 
asus zenfone 3 deluxe 
**blackberry keyone**
**htc explorer**
**lg tribute**
acer liquid z520
```

Comment: Why is the `z520` in `acer liquid z520` not being removed?

Comment: Don't need to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it should be the last word in a string and there are always multiple words, you might use:

```
[ \t]+(?=[a-zA-Z0-9/]{5})[a-zA-Z/]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9/]*[A-Za-z]$
```

- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ spaces or tabs
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9/]{5})` Assert at least 5 chars of any of the listed
- `[a-zA-Z/]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed
- `[0-9]` Match a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9/]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `[A-Za-z]` Match a char a-zA-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJswgx/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a positive look-ahead to the regex that requires the word at the end to contain at least one digit for it to be removed: `(?=\D*\d)`. That will prevent it from removing normal words that don't contain numbers.

The complete program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

texts = [
    'asus zenfone 3s max zc521tl',
    'asus zenfone max plus (m1) zb570tl',
    'asus zenfone max pro (m1) zb601kl/zb602k',
    'nokia 3.1 c',
    'nokia 3',
    'asus zenfone 3 zoom ze553k',
    'asus zenfone 3 deluxe zs570kl',
    'blackberry keyone',
    'htc explorer',
    'lg tribute',
    'acer liquid z520',
]

for text in texts:
    print(re.sub(r'(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9/]{5,}$', '', text))
```

It outputs:

```
asus zenfone 3s max 
asus zenfone max plus (m1) 
asus zenfone max pro (m1) 
nokia 3.1 c
nokia 3
asus zenfone 3 zoom 
asus zenfone 3 deluxe 
blackberry keyone
htc explorer
lg tribute
acer liquid z520
```